# How can I use url with more than one dots in volley librairy with kotlin in an android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I want to fetch data from my php backend using volley library in android using kotlin.
The problem is my url contains two dots and volley considers the first one as the end of the domain name, which it's not. So the url is not working in Volley but is working well in postman and in my brother.
This is the format of the url `https://xxxx.yyyy.net/mobile`, the first dot causes the problem.
How could I solve this problem?

I'm trying to change the url like `https://xxxx.net/yyyy/mobile` but this does not work because `yyyy` is not a subdomain but is a part of the domain name. 
My domain name has the format `xxxx.yyyy.net`

Comment: You can try encoding the URL before passing it to Volley. URL encoding replaces unsafe characters with their corresponding escape sequences, which can help resolve issues with special characters like dots.

Comment: val url = "https://xxxx.yyyy.net/mobile"    |  
val encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")

Comment: Thank you @mirsaidoff for your answer. After trying to encode the url, it still not work. I continue having the same problem

Comment: can you share your code here?

Comment: const val API_URL = "https://abtaxcoll.aretn.net/mobile/index.php/api/"
val stringReq: StringRequest =
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                object : StringRequest(
                    Method.POST,
                    URLEncoder.encode("${API_URL}authentication/login","UTF-8"),
                    Response.Listener { response ->
                       
                    },
                    Response.ErrorListener { error ->{
                    }
                )